# Edit multiple rows from the table

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have tied ODataModel with table using "TwoWay" binding. I need to allow user to edit the rows of the table at the bottom of which I have 'Save' button. Currently though the table is editable I am unable to edit the entries in multiple rows of the table.
Please find my code below:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("dprTable",{
        visibleRowCount: 4,
        visible: true,
        navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator
    });

    var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "DBR/DPR"}),
        template: new sap.m.Link({
            "target": "_blank",
            press:[controller.onClickDemoNo,controller]

        }).bindProperty("text","DemoId"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "DBR/DPR"
    });

    oTable.addColumn(oColumn);

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Description"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "DemoDesc"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Description"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Required Date"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("",{
            value:{
                path:"ReqDate",
                type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"})
            },
            change: function(){
                console.log('the date is changed and it\'s value is'+value);
            },


        }),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Required Date"
    }));


    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Requestor"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "RequestorName"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Requestor"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Requestor/Project Lead"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "LeadName"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Requestor/Project Lead"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Solution"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "SolutionText"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Solution"

    }));



    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Start Date"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("",{
            value:{
                path:"StartDate",
                type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"})
            }
        }),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Start Date"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "End Date"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("",{
            value:{
                path:"StartDate",
                type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy"})
            }
        }),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "End Date"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Estimated Duration"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "EstDuration"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Estimated Duration"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Hours"}),
        template: new sap.m.Input("",{}).bindProperty("value", "ActDuration"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Hours"

    }));

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Status"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox({items: [
            new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "New",key:"1"}),
            new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "In Process",key:"2"}),
            new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "Completed",key:"3"})
        ]}).bindProperty("value","StatusText"),
        width: "auto",
        tooltip: "Status"

    }));

    oTable.setBusyIndicatorDelay(1);
    //oData service call

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSECENTRAL_SRV",true);
    oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay");
    oModel.attachRequestSent(function (oEvent) {
        console.log('request sent');
         oTable.setBusy(true);
    });
    oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function () {
            console.log('request completed');
            oTable.setBusy(false);

    });
    oModel.attachRequestFailed(function () {
              oTable.setBusy(false);
    });

    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows("/DEOPENDBRSet");
```

Is there something pending in the settings? And to update the multiple records in the table do I have to make use of some batch operations? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OData, one http request can only contains one CRUD operation, unless using batch. Thus, for multiple records updating, suggest using batch

Comment: Thanks Maya, right said. I am not using "TwoWay" binding now. Instead of that I wrote change event handler for all the columns of the table on the fire of which I am adding one batch operation and on click of another "Save" button I have on screen, I am submitting the batch.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I am still searching for a solution.
Your original problem will be explained here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3372437

What I am still searching is, how can I fire "one" batch request with multiple changes (in different objects/entities) of one model?

I would expect something like:
    oModel.applyChangesAsBatch();

Where all changes on existing elements are done with binding controls.
In case of newly created entities of course there must be another call to create that on the model first.

In other words: Is there a way to use normal binding to the model and tell the model to send all changes in one request (maybe batch) to the server so that the server is able to store "all" or "nothing"?